# MVC 4 KendoUI Application doesn't populate data in the table grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

*Controller*

```
public List<Employee> Get()
{
    var ramadrmasextsOL = from a in db.EmpMas
                          select new KendoApplication.Models.Employee
                          {
                              EmployeeName = a.EmpNm,
                              EPFNumber = a.EPFNo,
                              NameWithInitial = a.NameInInitials
                          };
        return ramadrmasextsOL.ToList();
}
```

*View*

```
<div id="employeesGrid"></div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#employeesGrid").kendoGrid ({
            columns: [
                { field: "EmployeeName", title: "Employee Name" },
                { field: "EPFNumber", title: "EPF Number" },
                { field: "NameWithInitial", title: "Name With Initial" }
            ],
            pageable: true,
            dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: "Home/Get"
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

*Employee Model*

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string EPFNumber { get; set; }
        public string NameWithInitial { get; set; }
    }
```

OutPut -

Please could you help me to sort out this problem, I have attached Controller, View, Model with this question, Problem is the table doesn’t populate with  relevant database data, which populate just empty grid.

Comment: have you confirmed there is data in the ramadrmasextsOL.ToList()?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `List<Employee>` from the *controller*, return `JSON`.

```
public JsonResult Get()
{
    var ramadrmasextsOL = from a in db.EmpMas
        select new KendoApplication.Models.Employee
        {
            EmployeeName = a.EmpNm,
            EPFNumber = a.EPFNo,
            NameWithInitial = a.NameInInitials
        };
    return Json(ramadrmasextsOL, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Kendo understands `JSON` very well.. :)